# Specific If Else construct for JSF outPutText needed

Tags: java, jsf

i have the following code:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{clientBean.showPasswordChangeReminder and clientBean.daysUntilExpirePassword eq 0}">  
   <h:outputText value="#{txt.passwordChangeReminderDefault}" />
   <h:outputText value="#{txt.passwordChangeReminderSpecific}" />        
</h:panelGroup>
```

I need an if else construct to show only one of these two jsf output elements inside the panelgroup.

If clientBean.daysUntilExpirePassword > 1 when the output element with the value txt.passwordChangeReminderDefault" should been visible, else the output element with the value txt.passwordChangeReminderSpecific.

Is that possible to create this with an if else construct?

Thanks !

Comment: Just put a negation of the condition in `rendered` attribute in the other? Are you familiar at all with boolean logic?

Answer (score 2):

In JSF you would rather write

```
<h:outputText value="#{clientBean.daysUntilExpirePassword > 1 ? txt.passwordChangeReminderDefault : txt.passwordChangeReminderSpecific}" />
```

Comment: And if the `<h:outputText>` components are the only one within the `<h:panelGroup>` remove the group and use its rendered attribute at the single outputText